# Python Click Different Buttons

Tags: javascript, python, button, python-requests

Is there a way or method to click one of two different buttons in Python? The relevant HTML code for the two buttons is:

```
<input type="text" id="target" name="target" size="80" value="https://gj3s.inklingmarkets.com/user/good_judgment_authentication?u="style=\'display:none;\'>\n
<input type="button" id="training" name="training" style="width:200px;" value="Continue to Training" onclick="window.open(\'tr_redir.php\');" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="button" id="continue" name="continue" style="width:200px;" value="Continue to Forecasting Site"  onclick="pm_go();" />
```

The button I need to click when I access manually the website is the second (last row) with id="continue" and onclick="pm_go();"
I tried with requests post and get methods without success.

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()
r = s.post(Log_URL, data={"target":'https://gj3s.inklingmarkets.com/memberships/2010/profile'})
```

The script pm_go provides the target webpage

```
function pm_go(){
    var target_path = document.getElementById('target').value;
    if( target_path == '' ){
        alert("A target path is not yet defined for this Condition.");
    } else {
document.location = "pm_redir.php?target=" + target_path;
}
```

Comment: way to do it is by observing the requests in the net tab of browser. The information you provided doesn't help us answer that - can you please provide the website link and then advise what is to be done - I should probably be able to help then

Comment: @md-mohsin, I tried to add details, per your request; what do you mean by "observing the requests in the net tab of browser"?

Comment: Thanks, but what you have sent is the js and png files.
That won't help. By net tab I mean the network tab of your chrome or firefox. Can you please keep it open - click preserve log - and clickon the button you neeed to. Observe the requests and then send those requests here. Remember that when using requests --- be it a java button or just a link --- for most of the time - you dont need to look at html all you need is the net tab and that helps us navigate. Please comment with my name once you have that info, Thanks

Comment: @Md-Mohsin. I hope I'm following your instructions correctly: activated FN12 in Chrome; Network tab, preserve log, and record button on red. I'm not sure if there is a file I with the log that I can send you here. What I observed is that the first click where I enter the password uses the POST method; after that when I click the next button in the website, it is a GET method. I'm not sure how to send the requests. I appreciate your keeping up with my struggle.

Comment: can you please send the screenshot of the 2  requests. 
#1 The one you use post and login
#2 The get requests as you say when you click the java button.
You have to use sessions to continue both one after another.

Comment: @MD-Mohsin, I have attached the two screenshots. I hope that helps.

Comment: @MD-Mohsin, your prodding helped me find what I was doing wrong. Your help is appreciated

Comment: haha, I knew it would. I am happy :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the suggestions and prodding by @Md-Mohsin I recorded the session with Chrome FN12 the Network tab, preserve the log. What I discovered was that after sign in authorization, I was supposed to enter a URL with a target.
The URL parameter I was using for the requests.Session().get was

```
https://gj3s.inklingmarkets.com/ + something else
```

instead the URL above is supposed to be passed as a target parameter in a different, longer URL

```
https://www.goodjudgmentproject.com/forecasting/pm_redir.php?target=https://gj3s.inklingmarkets.com/user/good_judgment_authentication?u=
```

The recorded log of the showed all the addresses, in the POST and in the GET action to log in. I found the one I pasted above. I guess that's what the JavaScript was doing. So now my code to access the website in two steps is

```
user= 'my_e-mail_address@gmail.com'; pw = 'my_password'
Log_URL= 'https://www.goodjudgmentproject.com/forecasting/login.php'
Welcome_URL= 'https://www.goodjudgmentproject.com/forecasting/pm_redir.php?target=https://gj3s.inklingmarkets.com/user/good_judgment_authentication?u='
s = requests.Session()
r = s.post(Log_URL, data={"email":user, "password":pw})
r = s.get(Welcome_URL)
```